# Perform a rowwise comparison in data.table to make ordered groups

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

My data consists of pairs of observations about a collection of widgets, but the pairs can be in any order.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
dt <- data.table(
  V1 = c("B", "A", "D", "A", "G", "B", "C", "C", "E", "C"),
  V2 = c("A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "E", "D", "B", "B", "G")
)
```

I would like to be able to list the different widgets in my collection (A:B and B:A are the same thing).
dplyr does this successfully with:

```
ordered <- dt %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(widget= paste(sort(c(V1, V2)), collapse = ":")) %>%
  group_by(widget) %>% 
  distinct(widget)
```

As my dataset is large and the observations very long, I would like to convert the code to data.table, but cannot find an appropriate rowwise operation.
I suspect it might be an lapply thing, on the lines of:

```
orderedDT <- dt[, 
                j= widget:=lapply(.SD, function(x){paste(sort(x),collapse = ":")}), 
                by = .(V1, V2), 
                .SDcols = c("V1", "V2")]
```

But that does not produce the correct result.  Thank you for reading this and for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
> as.data.table(unique(t(apply(dt, 1, sort))))
   V1 V2
1:  A  B
2:  C  D
3:  C  G
4:  B  E
5:  B  C
```

or

```
> dt[, .(widget = unique(paste0(pmin(V1, V2), ":", pmax(V1, V2))))]
   widget
1:    A:B
2:    C:D
3:    C:G
4:    B:E
5:    B:C
```

Comment: nice, and yes, the data can be displayed as a graph.  But I really need the speed-memory optimisation from data.table to make this work at volume.

Comment: You can see my update

Comment: neat as well, and I will test on the big stuff.

Comment: The second option is pure data.table and should be optimal. I'm suspicious of using base R t() in the first option and interrupting the pipe.

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved.  Nice solution, clever use of pmax() and pmin()

Comment: @mer_curius I, personally, prefer the second option.